# SQL automatically count matching values and display count in table cell

Tags: sql, mysql, count, sql-update

**Scenario:** Creating an SQL table with entries added via a browser based form to work as a guest sign-in form, with each 10th visit being free.

**Goal**: Upon each new row entry, SQL to reference the 'phone' value for each row, then automatically count the number of existing matches to that value in the table, and automatically display that value in the 'visits' cell for each corresponding row, dynamically adjusting that value as new entries are added.

**Visual table structure example:**

| id | name | phone | visits (these values to be automatic) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Paul | 079111 | 2 |
| 02 | Jane | 079222 | 3 |
| 03 | Jane | 079222 | 3 |
| 04 | Molly | 079444 | 1 |
| 05 | Paul | 079111 | 2 |
| 06 | Jane | 079222 | 3 |

**Use example:** If 'Jane' were added again with '079222', the count cell for every row with '079222' would automatically go to '4'.

How to achieve the above?

Comment: To get "automatic" values, create a view.

Comment: The solution is to use a normalized data model.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving you a straight answer, here is an example regarding land sale, which hopefully will get your answer if you invest some time on it.

Here is the scenario: 
The total space of a district is fixed. Its avaialbe space should be automatically deducted once an area in the disctrict is sold.

```
create table districts
(district_id int primary key, 
total_space int, 
space_available int);

create table area_sold 
(area_id int primary key,
area_space int,
area_district_id int, 
foreign key (area_district_id) references districts(district_id));
```

Now we populate the `districts` table with two instances:

```
insert into districts values (1, 1000,1000),(2,800,800);
```

Now how are we supposed to automatically update the space left after an area in its district is sold ? We do it by creating a trigger , which as the head part implies, shall be fired for each new row inserted on table `districts`.

```
delimiter //
create trigger space_after_sold after insert on area_sold for each row
begin

update districts set space_available=space_available-new.area_space 
where district_id=new.area_district_id;

end //

delimiter ;
```

Now let us sell some land:

```
insert into area_sold values(1,300,1),(2,400,2),(3,500,1);
select * from area_sold;
+---------+------------+------------------+
| area_id | area_space | area_district_id |
+---------+------------+------------------+
|       1 |        300 |                1 |
|       2 |        400 |                2 |
|       3 |        500 |                1 |
+---------+------------+------------------+
```

A total of three areas were sold, with 2 in district 1 and 1 in district 2. With the trigger in effect when we inserted the rows, that's what we have now for table `districts`:

```
select * from districts;
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
| district_id | total_space | space_available |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|           1 |        1000 |             200 |
|           2 |         800 |             400 |
+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Of course, in reality, it's more complex, such as another trigger is required to add the available space when a land sold is reclaimed. But that's another story.